# What is the difference between tfpt scorch and tfpt treeclean

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-power-tools

What is the difference between these two commands?

```
tfpt scorch /deletes /recursive /noprompt
tfpt treeclean /recursive /noprompt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) is pretty clear:

> *Scorch*        Ensure source control and the local disk are identical
>
> *Treeclean*     Delete files and folders not under version control

Treeclean just deletes files not under version control. Scorch deletes files not under version control **and** will ensure that the files that *are* being synchronized match the server version.

Comment: So treeclean is just a subset of scorch?  There are no other differences?